# Cant add data to databases on Spring Boot using Heroku postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, heroku

I've been trying to get a Rest Repository up and running using Heroku.  However, while the tables I'm using are being added to the datasource, I am unable to upload any rows of data.

[Shows that my tables are being added to postgres datasource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPfft.png)

I don't get any error messages or issues deploying the service, I just can't add data.

I've looked around the internet for solutions currently application.properties is a mess of different bits of code that I've copied on all the guides for how to get a database running.

```
#spring.h2.console.enabled=true
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
#spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.username=sa
#spring.datasource.password=
#spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true


#spring.main.banner-mode=off
#logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

#spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
#spring.datasource.url=postgres://npwovtbfrmcgap:8cb0a1d61d6608e756d4340bb79926156b43c5d602580ab21884d058b7adf230@ec2-52-23-14-156.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/deu5uhuf0in93s
#spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
#spring.datasource.username=${SPRING_DATABASE_USERNAME}
#spring.datasource.password=${SPRING_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
#spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.datasource.url=${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
spring.datasource.username=${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

For testing I used h2 and that worked fine with no issues.  Even though I've been eyeing using JDBC _DATABASE for it's easy setup, I've made a Database Configuration file.

```
package com.example.chess.Config;


import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        return new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();
    }
}
```

There isn't a whole lot here, but from my understanding I shouldn't need one if I'm using a JDBC Database.

Some ideas that I have...

Heroku could be forcing me to use their guide on preparing a Spring Boot App for production
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/preparing-a-spring-boot-app-for-production-on-heroku

I could put better @GeneratedValue typing on the code for tables I have.

```
package com.example.chess.Model;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Chat {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Column
    private int chatID;

    @Column
    private String chatMsg;

    public int getChatID() {
        return chatID;
    }

    public String getChatMsg() {
        return chatMsg;
    }

    public void setChatID(int chatID) {
        this.chatID = chatID;
    }

    public void setChatMsg(String chatMsg) {
        this.chatMsg = chatMsg;
    }
}
```

Past that I'm not really sure what to do.  Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks for all the help, however I still havent gotten it working.  I used heroku logs to find more data.  I also used spring.database.platform and spring.datasource.driver-class-name.  the code for application properties has been updated.

```
2020-02-18T02:22:38.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-02-18T02:22:41.021726+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:41.017  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$28f59fce] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-18T02:22:41.264675+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-02-18T02:22:41.264732+00:00 app[web.1]: .   ____          _            __ _ _
2020-02-18T02:22:41.264786+00:00 app[web.1]: /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
2020-02-18T02:22:41.264849+00:00 app[web.1]: ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
2020-02-18T02:22:41.264905+00:00 app[web.1]: \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
2020-02-18T02:22:41.264972+00:00 app[web.1]: '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
2020-02-18T02:22:41.265009+00:00 app[web.1]: =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
2020-02-18T02:22:41.265886+00:00 app[web.1]: :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.7.RELEASE)
2020-02-18T02:22:41.265938+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-02-18T02:22:41.335856+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:41.335  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2020-02-18T02:22:41.566210+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:41.565  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
2020-02-18T02:22:41.566423+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:41.566  WARN 4 --- [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Could not locate PropertySource: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/application/default": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
2020-02-18T02:22:41.570798+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:41.570  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.example.chess.ChessApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-02-18T02:22:42.945648+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:42.943  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-02-18T02:22:43.135659+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:43.135  INFO 4 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 157ms. Found 4 repository interfaces.
2020-02-18T02:22:43.711365+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:43.711  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=de70dafe-40e0-316f-93ef-ef4b324ee017
2020-02-18T02:22:43.965692+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:43.965  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cdb9cd1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-18T02:22:44.025903+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:44.025  INFO 4 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$28f59fce] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-02-18T02:22:44.561043+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:44.560  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 37710 (http)
2020-02-18T02:22:44.670131+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:44.669  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-02-18T02:22:44.670471+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:44.670  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2020-02-18T02:22:45.421352+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:45.421  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-02-18T02:22:45.421626+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:45.421  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3826 ms
2020-02-18T02:22:45.859027+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:45.858  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-02-18T02:22:46.292693+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:46.292  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-02-18T02:22:46.414129+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:46.413  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
2020-02-18T02:22:46.414131+00:00 app[web.1]: name: default
2020-02-18T02:22:46.414131+00:00 app[web.1]: ...]
2020-02-18T02:22:46.563652+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:46.563  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2020-02-18T02:22:46.566628+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:46.566  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2020-02-18T02:22:46.824490+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:46.824  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2020-02-18T02:22:47.331763+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:47.331  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2020-02-18T02:22:47.616894+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:47.616  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2020-02-18T02:22:47.624236+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:47.623  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@37e4d7bb
2020-02-18T02:22:48.869877+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:48.869  INFO 4 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-02-18T02:22:49.329464+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:49.329  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2020-02-18T02:22:50.308149+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:50.307  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-02-18T02:22:50.411820+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:50.409  WARN 4 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-02-18T02:22:50.461378+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:50.461  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2020-02-18T02:22:51.073701+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-02-18T02:22:50.863588+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:50.863  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 37710 (http) with context path ''
2020-02-18T02:22:50.865846+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-18 02:22:50.865  INFO 4 --- [           main] com.example.chess.ChessApplication       : Started ChessApplication in 12.027 seconds (JVM running for 12.976)
```

Comment: Anything in logs? Can try adding dialect for PostgreSQL to application properties.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been using logging.  I've added `spring.datasource.platform=postgres` to application.properties with no success.  What else can I add?  If I still don't have it working I'll look into logging as well as other ideas I have to getting it working in original question.

Comment: You should add logs. If you find any exception in logs, then you know where to start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dialect , driver-class name and database-platform as you have commented those.

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it.  Boy do I feel dumb, the problem was in the angular frontend I was posting and getting from localhost:8080.

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/letter").then(function (response){

        $scope.letter = response.data;


    });

  $scope.postLetter = function(letter)
  {
      var data = {
          contactName: contactName,
          email: email,
          message: message
      };
      $http.post("http://localhost:8080/letter", JSON.stringify(data));
      location.reload();
  };
```

Thanks again for everyone who tried helping.